# Azure App Insights API to get traces using Query in c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, rest

I'm trying to use Azure App Insights API using https://dev.applicationinsights.io/
Got the metrics data using this "https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/889f31e2-8281-4d8b-bb80-53a9f83d4a09/metrics/requests/duration?interval=PT1H", Passed the api key through headers.
But not able to get the Query:
Tried this:
https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/889f31e2-8281-4d8b-bb80-53a9f83d4a09/Query/traces | where operation_Id contains 62c5a318-c2cf-434e-a102-0e6efc0a84e7?interval=P7D

Getting Status Code as NotFound.

Any suggestions, Am I missing something?

Comment: Make sure query first works using a browser.  The browser may give better error message to help solve issue. I used browser and got following : {"error":{"message":"Valid authentication was not provided","code":"AuthorizationRequiredError"}}

Comment: Might also try downloading postman, a great way to test Restful APIs

Comment: In browser we are not passing api key, so that its giving that error, But in code we are passing the key in headers

Comment: Can any get this using AAD Authentication, Instead of apikey?

Comment: @JSM Please check my update

Answer (score 9):

According to my research, if you want to do query with Azure Application insight rest api, the URL should be like as below

```
https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/{appId}/query?query={1}&timespan={2}
```

For example

```
var client = new HttpClient();
            var appId = "";
            var query = "traces | where operation_Id contains '33f491236bb412419002b006e1c3058b'";
            var timespan = "P7D";
             var apiKey=""
            string url = string.Format("https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/{0}/query?query={1}&timespan={2}", 
                                appId,
                                query,
                                timespan);
            

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            request.Headers.Add("x-api-key", apiKey);
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(url);

            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request)) {

                var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(str));
                Console.Read();
                
            }
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to the [document](http://dev.applicationinsights.io/reference/get-query). Besides, you also can try the API vai the [explorer](http://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/query).

---

**Update**

If you want to Azure AD auth to access Azure application insights API, please refer to the following steps

1. Register Azure AD application in your tenant
2. Configure API permissions
   [image]
   [image]
3. [Create a client secret for the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-credentials-to-your-web-application)
4. Configure  assign `contributor` to the AD application in your Application Insights resource
5. call the api

```
// install sdl MSAL.NET to get access token

var client = new HttpClient();
            var appId = "";
            var query = "traces | where operation_Id contains '33f491236bb412419002b006e1c3058b'";
            var timespan = "P7D";
             var apiKey=""
            string url = string.Format("https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/{0}/query?query={1}&timespan={2}", 
                                appId,
                                query,
                                timespan);
            string ClientId = "<your ad application clientID>";
            string ClientSecret = "<your ad application ClientSecret>";
            string tenant = "";

            var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                    .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
                    .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}"))
                    .Build();
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://api5.applicationinsights.io/.default" };
            var result =await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(url);

            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request)) {

                var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(str));
                Console.Read();
                
            }
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/AAD-Application-Setup)

Comment: Thank you very much, But I need to do the same thing using Azure Ad authentication, not using api key

Comment: what is ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder

Comment: Trying the solution, surely will make it as answer, once I completed

Comment: @JSM `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder` is a class in the package `Microsoft.Identity.Client` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplicationbuilder?view=azure-dotnet. We can use it to get Azure AD access token

Comment: Can we deserialize the data to access each object, I want to access rows object

Comment: @JSM You can try the code `var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var table =JToken.Parse(str);
               var s= table["tables"];
                var s1 = s.Children()["rows"].Children();
                foreach (var item in s1) {
                    // save one row vaule as a list 
                    var s2 = item.ToObject<List<string>>() ;
                   
                }`

Comment: Thanks, Can we remove the empty strings in the rows object?

Comment: Also needs to return the rows object in Json format

Comment: @JSM Regarding the issue of how to access Azure application insight api,  the issue has been reloved. If you have any other concerns, I suggest you post a new issue